# How to restrict access with Oauth 2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

New to Oauth and had a general question. Is there a way to restrict who can log into your site with Oauth 2? Similar to AD groups or something so I could control who I want to be able to log in based on group or user name? I would like people to use google or facebook but only let certain people actually log in.

Comment: Do you want to have a list of names or emails who can log in? Because you don't get any groups or roles from Google or Facebook. Please try to make the question more specific.

Comment: Yes say I want people to use facebook or google login but I only want like 10 specific people. Is limiting who can log in possible with oAuth?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter users in a code that handles the `redirect_uri`. If you use the [Auth code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1), that will be some backend code and if you use the [Implicit flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2), it will be a code in a browser application. But the JavaScript security restrictions should have their equivalent somewhere at the backend too, since the JavaScript code can be altered by the browser user.

To be able to do that (to have info about an authenticated user), you should either request an [ID token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) or an access token with a scope that authorizes you to get user info at the [`/userinfo`](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) endpoint.